# How do I search the auto-complete options?

Tags: spacemacs, company-mode

Spacemacs by default comes with company for autocomplete.
When typing, it shows all kinds of symbols matching what I have typed so far. This list can be **very** long.

Is there any way to search in the currently available completions?

**Example:**
Say I want to add a key to an evil-mode keymap.

`(define-key evil-` will show a bunch of options but now I would like to filter those for the ones that also contain `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `C-s` (`company-search-candidates`), use `C-h f company-search-candidates` to learn more:

> company-search-candidates is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `company.el`.
>
> (company-search-candidates)
>
> Start searching the completion candidates incrementally.
>
> Search can be controlled with the commands:
>
> - `company-search-repeat-forward` (C-s)
> - `company-search-repeat-backward` (C-r)
> - `company-search-abort` (C-g)
> - `company-search-delete-char` (DEL)
>
> Regular characters are appended to the search string.
>
> Customize `company-search-regexp-function` to change how the input is
>   interpreted when searching.
>
> The command `company-search-toggle-filtering` (C-o) uses the search
>   string to filter the completion candidates.